# golang exec a command on a running binary / process

Tags: go, operating-system, signals

If you look at Nginx it calls "nginx reload" to reload itself. Is there any　way to send a signal from the command line to a running process? Even if the main process starts child processes how can I send commands to the main to notify its children?

ex:

```
myapp start -debug // starts a server
myapp reload -gracefull // stops the app gracefully
```

Now i need to send os signals to notify my server to perform a graceful shutdown

```
kill -QUIT pid
kill -USR2 pid
```

I hope my question is clear enough
Thnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Receive signals

Take a look at the [`os/signal`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package.

> Package signal implements access to incoming signals.

There is even an [example](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#pkg-examples) in the documentation :

```
// Set up channel on which to send signal notifications.
// We must use a buffered channel or risk missing the signal
// if we're not ready to receive when the signal is sent.
c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

// Block until a signal is received.
s := <-c
fmt.Println("Got signal:", s)
```

## Send signals

To see how to send signals take a look at [`signal_test.go`](http://tip.golang.so/src/pkg/os/signal/signal_test.go), it uses [`syscall`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/). For example :

```
// Send this process a SIGHUP
t.Logf("sighup...")
syscall.Kill(syscall.Getpid(), syscall.SIGHUP)
waitSig(t, c, syscall.SIGHUP)
```

Comment: I know this and i use this in my program. But i want it to send a signal to its own process from the commandline

Comment: and if my program is already running and i want to send it a sig from its own cli? app -quit. its a different pid right?

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester I guess you can store the pid in a local file or in an environment variable.

Comment: I call the same binairy with its cli but they dont share os.Env

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester Do they share the same file system? When binary starts write PID number to a PID file, then when you want to reload read PID file for PID number.

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester that's what a lot of programs do, usually store the pid in /run/appname.pid, or if you want to send more than a signal you would listen on a socket (usually unix socket but tcp works too).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in go i we can pass the environment to syscall.Exec

```
err := syscall.Exec(argv0. os.Args. os.Environ())
```

simply copies the current env to the child process.